# How do I pass configuration values to constructor in case of dependency implementation

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I am using Autofac for IoC

Here is the constructor of my class which takes `IProcessor` and `size` as parameters

```
public GatewayClient(IProcessor processor,
      int size)
{
   _size = size;
   _processor = processor;
}
```

Here is my container initiator class, whose responsibility is to register the dependencies.

```
var size = Convert.ToInt32(configuration.GetValue<string>("Settings:SizeInKb"));

builder.RegisterType<Processor>().As<IProcessor>().SingleInstance();
builder.Register(c => new GatewayClient(size)).As<IGatewayClient>().SingleInstance();
```

The error says as follow

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'processor' of 'GatewayClient(IProcessor, int)'  MyProject.GatewayService    C:\work\GatewayService\ContainerInitiator.cs

Question is, How do I pass the `size` to the constructor? it shall be taken care of by `autofac` right?

Comment: You're passing `Func<IComponentContext, GatewayClient>` to Autofac. You're the one constructing the `GatewayClient`, not `Autofac`. Presumably parameterless works because you also have a parameterless constructor.

Comment: @John This is not a duplicate question. How do I pass 'size' parameter is the question?

Comment: So your question isn't why you're getting the error?

Comment: question is how to pass  'size' so that i resolve the error. Please remove duplicate so that someone can help to answer the question. it's related to dependency injection not about simple paramter passing.

Comment: Understood. I've added a second duplicate which answers that part of the question.